# How to display featured image?

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image

I am simply trying to display featured image in my custom wordpress theme in my div structure as a background image.

NEW EDIT here is the whole page so you can see exaclty what is or is not inside the loop. I also have checked to see if featured image is assigned to the post and it is. I have also checked my functions.php and that too is set up to use thumbnails.

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
        <div class="page-section clear">
            <div class="container clear">
                <div class="news">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="news-left">
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) : 
                ?>
                            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID); // returns an array ?>
                            <div class="news-image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>');"></div>


                        <?php    endif; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <main role="main">
                    <!-- section -->
                    <section>
                        <h1><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?> </h1>
                        <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
                    </section>
                    <!-- /section -->
                    </main>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please can you be more specific as to what the issue is, provide screenshots or add a jsfiddle example..

Comment: There aren't any issues besides I can't find out how to display my featured image. I've done research and looked at related questions and still can't find the answer.It's a very simple question. No hidden meaning. @AaronHatton

Comment: are you referring to http://en.support.wordpress.com/featured-images/ ?

Comment: see edits @AaronHatton

Comment: To be honest, your question needs much more depth, you need more snippets of code, explain what you have done. You have mentioned that it is a custom theme but not as to if it is 100% bespoke or another which you have modified, we need to know what changes you have made to your theme which could have potentially broken this functionality. You can't say a needle is broken in a haystack now go fix it because it will be impossible!

Comment: @AaronHatton What needle in a haystack? This is a very SIMPLE and straight forward question. I added more code if you see edits. The two people who answered it didn't seem to have any confusion in what I was asking...

Comment: @user2684452 does it display the div at least?

Comment: Can you confirm if the `.news-image` is actually displaying at all? Is it the `<div>` that isn't displaying or the background image?

Comment: @Howlin this is what the source code renders <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="news-left">
  </div>
</div> in other words it's empty and not displaying the div or thumbnail.

Comment: Then it is a problem with `if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ))`, what is the code before it? To use that you have to use it in the [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: @Howlin the proper div is being wrapped in the loop. the news-image is not being displayed because it's in the loop and not registering somehow. .news-left should not be in the loop and always be there as is

Comment: I'd suggesting putting up more of the code so we can work out why `has_post_thumbnail()` isn't returning anything. Are you positive this is in the loop, the `$post` variable actually contains an object and that this post does actually have a featured image assigned?

Comment: @Dre Yes I am looking at the featured image. I will post more code see edits....

Comment: You're not calling `has_post_thumbnail()` within the loop, so at that point $post hasn't been setup yet. Try putting `global $post` before you try and fetch the image

Comment: @Dre I messed up on the last edit. Please see refreshed edits with the proper loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [wp get attachment image src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID); // returns an array ?>

<div class="news-image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>');"></div>
```

Comment: didn't work. I even tried adding add_filter( 'icon_dir', 'my_theme_icon_directory' );
add_filter( 'icon_dir_uri', 'my_theme_icon_uri' );

function my_theme_icon_directory( $icon_dir ) {
 return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/images';
}

function my_theme_icon_uri( $icon_dir ) {
 return get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images'; 
} in the functions.php

Comment: @user2684452 Didn't work in what way? Did it display anything on the background-image?

Comment: Do you do this in loop?

Comment: @user2684452 Also can you post some of the code before and after that div? (you can edit it into your question).

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that your `if` conditional doesn't evaluate as `true`, which means `has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )` isn't returning anything, which in turn means that **either this particular post doesn't have a featured image assigned or (more likely) `$post->ID` isn't a valid argument to pass to the function.** In other words, it's probable that at that point in your template `$post` doesn't contain anything, since it's not being requested in the loop. **You need to check if `$post->ID` is actually a valid post number.** Try to either make your call within the loop, or try adding `global $post` *before* your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Wordpress, then simply get a url of featured image:

```
<div class="news-image" style="background-image:url('<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src('large'); ?>');"></div>
```

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) is description about featured images urls